# Ball doesn't move around screen

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

Hi i am creating a mini tennis game but for some reason the ball doesn't move on the screen. i have managed to create the bats and they both move. the ball requires to bounce off the bat and go in any directiong. Any Ideas??

Comment: So, where do you call the `move` method of the `Ball` class?

Comment: hi i am aware that i havent done this fort this might be the reason i am new to java to dont know where to call it in the Drawing panel class

Comment: So, you need to think about what action, in the game, will start the ball moving.  For example, is there a key that a player should press, to serve the ball?  I think you need to give some thought to how the game should work, before you write more code.

Comment: hi @DavidWallace thanks for the advice i have thought of that the ball will get triggered by the player pressing the space button, so what would i require to do this like a key binding?

Comment: So you'll need some kind of flag to indicate whether the ball is in play.  When they press the space bar, if the flag is not set, you should set the flag, create a `Ball` object, and start some kind of timer that calls the `move` method at regular intervals.

Comment: hi thanks for that will this be some kind of if statement and will i need to create a few methods such as key pressed, key released for the ball? @DavidWallace

Answer (score 2):

What you need for animation is a `javax.swing.Timer`. This is the basic construct

```
Timer(int delay, ActionListener listener)
```

For every so many milliseconds, the timer will fire an `ActionEvent` which will be listened for in the `ActionListener` you pass to it.  So in your case, you'd want to call the `ball.move()` method to get the `ball` to animate.

The below code is *all* that I added, to the constructor of the `MyDrawingPanel`, and it animates fine.  Note: I used your code from yesterday in a different question posted, so I can't guarantee the same results with your current code, if you've made changes.

```
    Timer timer = new Timer(20, new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ball.move();
            repaint();
        }
    });
    timer.start();
```

You can of course have a separate button where you can call the `timer.start()` or `timer.stop()` and maybe have a reset button where you set the ball to a default location. But for now, the above should bring your animation to life.

Comment: mate u have been so helpful in my questions, this has worked previously i tried calling the move method of the ball class but i didn't get nowhere because i didn't add the time and i didn't recall the paint method,i do have a new Game button in my gui but i haven't got it to do anything i require it to restart the game to its orginal state once clicked any ideas?

Comment: You can call the `timer.start()` from the game button`. Declare the timer as a global variable in the `MyDrawingPanel` class. Have a getter for the timer, if the game button is in a different class. Then you can do something like `Timer timer = myDrawingPanel.getTimer(); timer.start();` In the method of the game start button. If the game start button is in the the same class as the `MyDrawingPanel`, then all you need to do is declare it as a global variable and call `timer.start()`

Comment: I recommend you also look at the [types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/rendering.html) of rendering. For more information, see [this](http://jamesgames.org/resources/double_buffer/double_buffering_and_active_rendering.html).